# 'UseSegmentedControlViewController.h' file not found

Tags: iphone

The line

```
#import <UseSegmentedControlViewController.h>
```

in my little attempt to do a segmented control has led to the error

'UseSegmentedControlViewController.h' file not found

The lines

```
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
```

are all fine.

is there some particular framework I should be loading?

I currently have:

- AudioToolbox
- CoreMotion
- CoreLocation
- UIKit
- Foundation
- CoreGraphics

TIA
Dr. J

Comment: AS it is your own created class, you should be using  
`#import "UseSegmentedControlViewController.h"`

Comment: if it still doesnt find it let me know.

Comment: loading for any specific work?

Answer (score 1):

If `UseSegmentedViewController.h` is a view controller you wrote, you want to surround the file name in double quotes (`"`), not angle brackets. Angle brackets are used only for system-provided headers, not headers in your own project.